# How can I insert a shortcode in the title tag of another?

Tags: shortcode, title

```
//Shortcode which return a name
[get_name]
//A heading of the theme. I need text + shortcode in title=""
[dt_fancy_title title="My name: [get_name]"]
//I tried this but it doesn´t work
[dt_fancy_title title="My name: "][get_name][/dt_fancy_title]
```

I use many headings or other widgets with different titles. The text is different in every title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that, as the title argument is passed as a string.

Given the information you provided, I suppose that your `[dt_fancy_title]` shortcode does not actually execute shortcodes.

The syntax for this function should be:

```
function dt_fancy_title_callback( $params, $content = null ) {

    // extract the title argument from the params, setting default value
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => 'default title'
    ), $params ) );

    // execute your function, whatever it does

    // call for shortcodes to be executed within your shortcode
    $content = do_shortcode( $content );

    // return the content
    return $content;

}
add_shortcode( 'dt_fancy_title', 'dt_fancy_title_callback' );
```

If you do not call the `do_shortcode()` in your callback function, the shortcode texts inside will be interpreted as a string.